# What is rate of change of Earth's gravity (jerk, 3rd derivative of position)?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, kinematics

We know that gravity changes with height so there must exist a jerk. Could I know the method to find it. Does there exists jounce(4th derivative of position) for Earth's gravity?

Comment: What stops you from differentiating the Earth's gravitational field yourself?

Comment: Laziness isn't a good reason to outsource your work to others. As for "not knowing the approach", what exactly are you finding difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the acceleration

$$\mathbf{a}=-\frac{GM\mathbf{r}}{r^3},$$

the jerk on a point mass in an inverse-square field isn't a function only of position. It depends on the velocity as well, and thus on the details of the initial conditions:

$$\mathbf{j}=\frac{d\mathbf{a}}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(-\frac{GM\mathbf{r}}{r^3}\right)=-GM\left(\frac{\mathbf{v}}{r^3}-\frac{3\dot{r}\mathbf{r}}{r^4}\right)=-GM\left(\frac{\mathbf{v}}{r^3}-\frac{3(\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{r})\mathbf{r}}{r^5}\right).$$

There are nonzero higher time-derivatives-of-position of all orders. Just keep differentiating. You can reduce all of them to $GM$ times a linear combination $\mathbf r$ and $\mathbf v$ with scalar coefficients constructed from $\mathbf r$ and $\mathbf v$.